# How can I sum all numbers with a certain tag in an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, scripting

Here are a few lines from an example XML file:

```
<media:content url="randomurl1" duration="51" medium="video"/>
<media:content url="randomurl2" duration="28" medium="video"/>
<media:content url="randomurl3" duration="72" medium="video"/>
```

I want to sum all of the duration values, so 51, 28, and 72, for example. Is there any neat way to do this? I'm very new to this. Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: *"Is there any neat way to do this?"* [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html): `sum(//content/@duration)`

Comment: Do you have a well-formed XML?

Comment: My XML file is formatted exactly like the example, but with many many more lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to sum the xml element in JAVA

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
    {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
            { 
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        sum += Double.parseDouble(eElement.getElementsByTagName("duration").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
    }
System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
```

Comment: @kjhughes its a sample piece of code which will help him to understand,

Comment: It would help him more if it weren't wrong, and you would know it was wrong if you even tried to run it.  You should fix it, verify that it's working, and update.  If you can't be bothered to do that, you should delete it.

Comment: Sorry @kjhughes  am not agree , as code will work fine for sum as he wants.

Comment: How do I import my xml file using this code? Sorry, I'm very inexperienced

Comment: @ColeSmith you can follow this link https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/